# Eloquent ORM with multiple models

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, orm, eloquent

I'm trying to create a new web application, currently I have created a static array with some information which looks like this:

```
array(5) { 
    ["id"]=> int(1) 
    ["firstname"]=> string(6) "martin" 
    ["lastname"]=> string(1) "r" 

    ["school"]=> array(3) { 
        ["id"]=> string(1) "3" 
        ["name"]=> string(22) "tallinna polütehnikum" 
        ["role"]=> string(7) "student" 
    } 

    ["lessons"]=> array(2) { 
        [0]=> array(3) { 
            ["id"]=> int(1) 
            ["name"]=> string(10) "eesti keel" 
            ["grades"]=> array(2) { 
                [0]=> array(2) { 
                    ["id"]=> int(1) 
                    ["grade"]=> int(4) 
                } 
                [1]=> array(2) { 
                    ["id"]=> int(3) 
                    ["grade"]=> int(5) 
                } 
            } 
        }

        [1]=> array(3) {
            ["id"]=> int(2) 
            ["name"]=> string(11) "matemaatika" 
            ["grades"]=> array(1) {
                [0]=> array(2) { 
                    ["id"]=> int(2) 
                    ["grade"]=> int(3)
                } 
            } 
        } 
    } 
}
```

Also I have models like this:

- User
- School
- Grade
- Lesson

Lessons table has *school_id* foreign key.

School table has *admin_id* foreign key.

Grades table has *lesson_id*, *teacher_id*, *user_id* foreign keys.

I'm having troubles generating a dynamic array like I showed before.
I tried using

```
->with('grades')->with('lessons')
```

but it didn't do anything like I wanted to.

Maybe someone can give me some directions?

Comment: oh yeah, using laravel 5.4, if that's important.

Comment: Please don't poste code as image. Format your text as code, it will make life easier for people wanting to help you

Comment: oops, gonna fix this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try like this:

```
App\User::with('school', 'grades', 'lessons')->find(1)->toArray();
```

You should get an array similar to one you wanted.